# Change specific row color in javaFX

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

Here is the code i write to change row color where leather's meter < 200 but i face null pointer exception in if condition. First i get all data from database and add them all to table view so i don't expect null pointer exception. What is the problem?

```
    @FXML
    TableView<Leather> tableView;
    ObservableList<Leather> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        tableView.setEditable(true);
        codeCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("code"));
        colorCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("color"));
        meterCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("meter"));

        indexCol.setCellFactory(col -> new TableCell<Task, String>() {
            @Override
            public void updateIndex(int index) {
                super.updateIndex(index);
                if (isEmpty() || index < 0) {
                    setText(null);
                } else {
                    setText(Integer.toString(index+1));
                }
            }
        });

        data.addAll(storeService.getAll());
        tableView.setItems(data);

        tableView.setRowFactory(tv -> new TableRow<Leather>(){
            @Override
            protected void updateItem(Leather item, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item,empty);
                if (item.getMeter()<200){
                    setStyle("-fx-background-color: #DB8A6B");
                }
            }
        });
     }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to handle all cases in your `rowFactory` (in the same way you do in your `cellFactory`):

```
    tableView.setRowFactory(tv -> new TableRow<Leather>(){
        @Override
        protected void updateItem(Leather item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item,empty);
            if (empty || item == null) {
                setStyle("");
            } else if (item.getMeter()<200){
                setStyle("-fx-background-color: #DB8A6B");
            } else {
                setStyle("");
            }
        }
    });
```